# Why do I get an error "exit() redefinition" while using OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, c++

I am using Visual C++ 2010 and I get the following errors:

```
1>d:\visual c++\vc\include\stdlib.h(353): error C2381: 'exit' : redefinition; __declspec(noreturn) differs
1>d:\glut-3.7.6-bin\include\gl\glut.h(146) : see declaration of 'exit'
```

In my project I have 3 files.  Here are the includes from each of them.

Main.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include "BmpLoader.h"
#include<glut.h>
```

BmpLoader.h

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<glut.h>
#include<Windows.h>
```

BmpLoader.cpp

```
#include "BmpLoader.h"
```

As far as I know, I receive this error due to the include order.  I have tried so far several arrangements of the includes, but haven't figured out the proper arrangement.

What library combination causes this error and what include order should I use in order to prevent it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `glut.h` defines a new `exit()` function, which overrides the one in `stdlib.h` (included by `Windows.h`). This problem has also been addressed on Stack Overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14402/glut-exit-redefinition-error).

The solution is to include `Windows.h` *before* `glut.h`.